# Cakephp 3 Element file is missing

Tags: html, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have the problem that my navbar.ctp element isnt loading i only get the error message from cakephp

Element file "Element/navbar.ctp" is missing.

My code in my default layout of cakephp (because i want the navbar in all "views")

```
<?php
    echo $this->element('navbar');
?>
```

and my element is in Layout/Element/navbar.ctp

So i dont unterstand why it says me that my element is missing.
Do i have anything missing?
I hope someone could help me with the problem. I dont have much information, because its not complicated per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the file in the wrong folder.

Check the cookbook:

> Elements live in the **src/Template/Element/** folder, and have the .ctp
>   filename extension. They are output using the element method of the
>   view:
>
> ```
> echo $this->element('helpbox');
> ```

Source: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views.html#elements

Comment: Exactly right. The place for this file is `src/Template/Element/navbar.ctp`, not `src/Template/Layout/Element/navbar.ctp`.